# How to redirect to another page using jquery with paramether

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, datatable

i write index page using bootstrap data table and .net mvc and i want my last column to be redirect button to order details. I filled datatable using ajax/jquery and maked button in this last column. When i click on it nothing happend and i get following error: **identifier starts immediately after numeric literal**.

I put my code bellow

```
    $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $('#ordersList').DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                "type" : "GET" ,
                "url" : "@Url.Action("GetData","OrderManager")" ,
                "datatype" : "json"
                },
                "columns":
                [
                { "data" : "CreatedAt" },
                { "data" : "FirstName" },
                { "data" : "Surname" },
                { "data" : "Email" },
                { "data": "OrderStatus" },
                { "data": "Id" , "render" : function ( data ) {
                    return "<a class= 'btn btn-danger' onclick = Menage(" + data + ")> Menage</a>";
                    }}
                ]
            });
        });

    function Menage( id ) {
            var url = '@Url.Action("UpdateOrder", "OrderManager", new { id = "__id__" })';
            window.location.href = url.replace('__id__', id);
    }
```

Controller name is: OrderManagerController
Action is: UpdateOrder

```
public ActionResult UpdateOrder(string Id)
        {
            ViewBag.StatusList = new List<string>() {
                "Order Created",
                "Order Processed",
                "Order Shipped",
                "Order Complete"
            };
            Order order = orderService.GetOrder(Id);
            return View(order);
        }
```

Comment: Try adding quotes to your onclick `onclick='Menage(" + data + ")'>`

Comment: Always check what has been *rendered*/sent to the browser, not the server-side / Razor code.  Your `data` may be creating something odd - show the the rendered HTML for the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to update your `Menage` button render code by adding quotes around `Menage` function and `data` like:

```
return "<a class= 'btn btn-danger' onclick='Menage(\"" + data + "\")'> Menage</a>";
```